# When I add a lib to a project from maven. How do I find out classes I can use?

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

Documentation of said library says to import a specific class, and different one for older versions.

I tried both and none are recognized by android studio as exisiting.

How do I find out if an mavenCentral() library has been downloaded and included to my android project??

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find out if an mavenCentral() library has been downloaded and included to my android project?

If you added the appropriate line to your module's Gradle build script (e.g., `implementation ...`), it should be there, or you would have gotten a build error complaining about not being able to download the artifact.

You can see what libraries are available to your overall project in Android Studio by first switching the project tree from the Android view to the Project view via the drop-down above the tree:

[image: Android Studio Project Tree, Showing Drop-Down]

[image: Android Studio Project Tree, Showing Project View]

If you scroll down in the tree, you will find a "External Libraries" branch of the tree that you can expand:

[image: Android Studio Project Tree, Showing External Libraries]

This lists all of the libraries available to the whole project, including those from tests, transitive dependencies, etc.

Comment: How can I view gradle build errors? In general is was previously graving out, I launched some command and it seemed like it was pulling sependencies from maven. Added a line to implemntation that seemed to look like so: implementation "'com.reverse.www:artifact:version"; but I don't have anything in the project itself, or does the implementation has to follow a different scheme?

Comment: @JakubStrzelecki: "How can I view gradle build errors?" -- Android Studio will show them to you in the Build tool pane, docked by default on the bottom of the IDE window. "but I don't have anything in the project itself, or does the implementation has to follow a different scheme?" -- you might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you say what library you are trying to use and you provide a [mcve] including the `build.gradle` file.